# Partial template specialization triggering static_asserts

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this code

```
template <typename T>
struct delay : std::false_type{};

template <typename T>
struct my_typelist {
    static_assert(delay<T>{}, "");
};

template <typename Tuple>
struct test;

template <typename T>
struct test<my_typelist<T>> {
    void pass(){}
};

template <typename T>
void fail(const test<T> &){}

int main()
{
    test<my_typelist<int>> t;
    t.pass();
    fail(t);
}
```

Without calling `fail()` the code compiles and runs fine. However, using `t` in any function seems to trigger the `static_assert` in the `my_typelist` class, even though the class is never instantiated. Though the example is contrived, I ran into the same issue using incomplete types inside a `std::tuple`, even though I simply used `std::tuple` as a type list and never instantiated it.

Why does the `static_assert` only trigger once I use the variable as a parameter, and not when I call a member function? In what contexts is `my_typelist` instantiated and when is it not?

Note that I would have used variadic template but the error occurs regardless of this so I opted in to using the lowest common denominator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case of `fail(t)`, if `my_typelist<int>` declares a friend function named `fail` in its class definition, that function will be found by [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (because `my_typelist<int>` is an associated class of `test<my_typelist<int>>`). In certain cases, that friend, instead of the global function `fail`, may get selected by overload resolution ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b464a6cbeb78c8c)). Therefore, the definition of `my_typelist<int>` must be instantiated and examined to see whether that happens. Adding parentheses around `fail` will suppress argument-dependent lookup and remove the need to instantiate `my_typelist<int>`, and in that case, `static_assert` is not triggered ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3932415276d3f87f)).

In the case of `t.pass()`, `my_typelist<int>` is not instantiated because it is known that `t.pass()` will always call a member function of `test<my_typelist<int>>`, and that won't be affected by the completeness of `my_typelist<int>`.

Answer (score 7):

So, let us go this way:

First change your `static_assert` from this [working code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/568ce7e649e6f611):

```
template <typename T>
struct my_typelist {
    static_assert(delay<T>{}, "");
};
```

to this:

```
template <typename T>
struct my_typelist {
    static_assert(false, "");
};
```

It is going to [fire immediately](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d03a18bff4a6b51). Note that the `false` expression doesn't depend on any type.

---

Now, change it to a `delay<T>` type that doesn't depend on any template parameter, say, `char`, `int`, etc:

```
template <typename T>
struct my_typelist {
    static_assert(delay<int>{}, "");
};
```

It is still going to [fire immediately](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/715c8a6f44b0073b).

---

So what's happening here?

class templates are not implicitly instantiated even when used, unless its used in contexts that requires completely defined types.

[temp.inst/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#inst-1)

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly
>   instantiated ([temp.explicit]) or explicitly specialized
>   ([temp.expl.spec]), the class template specialization is implicitly
>   instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that
>   requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of
>   the class type affects the semantics of the program.

See, [@cpplearner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41691028/1621391) to understand why calling the function `fail(...)` instantiates `my_typelist<int>`. Basically ADL kicks in which forces such instantiation, you can suppress using a qualified name `::foo` or parenthesis.

For completeness: In one of the [rules](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2) among [others for ADL](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep) (emphasis mine):

> [basic.lookup.argdep/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2): For each argument type T in the function call, there is a set of zero or more associated namespaces and a set of zero or more associated classes to be **considered**.
>
> - ....
> - [basic.lookup.argdep/2.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2.2): If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are:    the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any;
>     and its direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces
>     are the innermost enclosing namespaces of its associated classes. Furthermore, **if T is a class template specialization, its associated namespaces and classes also include: the namespaces and classes associated with the types of the template arguments provided for template type parameters (excluding template template parameters); the namespaces of which any template template arguments are members; and the classes of which any member templates used as template template arguments are members.** [ Note: Non-type template arguments do not contribute to the set of associated namespaces. — end note ]
> - ....

Comment: So, why `t.pass();` does not require `my_typelist<int>` to be a completely defined type, and why `fail(t);` does require `my_typelist<int>` to be a complete type?

Comment: I fail to see how this is a situation where the completely-defined object type is needed or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics. Changing the `fail` function into `fail(...)` still triggers the error, and changing the `static_assert` to check for completeness of type and using a forward declared struct also triggers this error.

Comment: @cpplearner, As per the quoted text. The size of the object of type `t` which is `test<my_typelist<T>>` is always known irrespective of what the template parameter `T` is. Of cause, the type of `t` certainly involves the name `my_typelist<int>`, only as a type not as a completely defined type at that time, even if [forward declared](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac15bc0e7bcdbfcd); As for why `my_typelist<int>` is instantiated on calling `fail`, ADL kicks in to examine the associated class, calling `::fail` (globaly qualified) prevents it. EDIT: As you've rightly answered.